# Ajax responseText not being displayed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have written an Ajax script in "home.jsp" page which delegates the request object to "like.jsp" page which then calls a servlet method returning boolean value.
I am trying to display this boolean value in an html element(<'span'> tag).
Here is the Ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function like()
    {
        alert('g');
        var i = "a1eec";
        var xmlhttp;    
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

        try{  
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=getInfo;  
            xmlhttp.open("GET","like.jsp?q="+i,true);  
            xmlhttp.send();  
            }
        catch(e){
            alert("Unable to connect to server");
        }  
    }  


    function getInfo(){ 

        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            //alert('p');
            var val=xmlhttp.responseText;  
            document.getElementById("flike").innerHTML=val;  
        }
        else if(xmlhttp.readyState!=4)
        {
            //alert('t');
            document.getElementById("flike").innerHTML=val;  
        }
    }
```

The like.jsp page code:

```
<body>
<%  
    System.out.print("IT IS LIKE>JSP");
    String name = (String)session.getAttribute("email");
    String text_id = request.getParameter("q");
    boolean flag = service1.likes(text_id, name);

    if(flag)
        out.print(flag);
    else
        System.out.println("Not");

    //response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
%>
```

The var '**val**''s value is not being displayed in desired element.
I have tested servlet and like.jsp page giving manual input and there is no problem but just in case you notice anything going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your xmlhttp variable [is out of scope](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/).

> If I define a function and create variables inside it, those variables
>   becomes locally scoped. Any locally scoped items are not visible in
>   the global scope - unless exposed, meaning if I define functions or
>   variables within a new scope, it's inaccessible outside of that
>   current scope.

By defining it in `like()` you have limited its use outside of `like()`, and it shows up as `undefined` in `getInfo()`.

Move the variable declaration outside of the `like()` function like so:

```
var xmlhttp;  

function like() {
    var i = "a1eec";  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    //... 
}  

function getInfo(){ 
    console.log(xmlhttp)
    //...
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omehexyw/1/).

Comment: Thank you Michael for pointing out that silly mistake I made there. I went codeblind looking for the problem but now its working..thanx again! :)

Comment: @HarshVardhan You can accept/up vote if it helped. ;)